# getCurrentSession hibernate in web

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am writing a web based application with hibernate and jsp/servlet. I have read about the `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession` and `sessionFactory.openSession` methods. I know the basic difference between them (using `getCurrentSession` you don't have to close the connection and when you commit the transaction, your session will automatically close). According to the my understanding, we should opt for `getCurrentSession` and do it through session-per-request.

Let's consider the following scenario:

1. Method A calls `getCurrentSession` and got the current session
2. In Method A, a transaction is started using the session from step 1
3. Method A calls Method B, which also has `getCurrentSession` and starts a transaction
4. Method B commits its transaction
5. Control returns to method A and it also commits the transaction

Now my questions are

1. Will the session found in step 1 and step 3 will be the same session?
2. If the answer for the question 1 is yes, then how would it handle the commit in step 4? Ideally it should close the session there itself and should throw an exception at step 5.
3. If the answer for the question 1 is no, then how do you handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 7):

> Will the session found in step 1 and step 3 will be the same session?

They should be the same, that's somehow part of the contract of `getCurrentSession()` and you'll get the `Session` bound to the thread as long as the unit of work has not been completed (i.e. a transaction has been committed or rolled back). *Java Persistence with Hibernate* puts it like this (p.481):

> All the data-access code that calls `getCurrentSession()` on the global shared
>   `SessionFactory` gets access to the same current `Session` — if it’s called in the
>   same thread. The unit of work completes when the `Transaction` is committed (or rolled back). Hibernate also flushes and closes the current `Session` and its persistence context if you commit or roll back the transaction. The implication here is that a call to `getCurrentSession()` after commit or rollback produces a new `Session` and a fresh persistence context.

And you might also want to read what the javadoc of [`Session#beginTransaction()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction()) says.

> If the answer for the question 1 is yes, then how would it handle the commit in step 4. Ideally it should close the session there itself and should give error at step 5.

Step 4 shouldn't be a problem, the `Session` will be flushed, the `Transaction` will be committed and the `Session` closed. But I expect step 5 to fail wih a[`TransactionException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/TransactionException.html) (that's my bet). But let me quote the javadoc of [`Transaction`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Transaction.html):

> A transaction is associated with a Session and is usually instantiated by a call to `Session.beginTransaction()`. A single session might span multiple transactions since the notion of a session (a conversation between the application and the datastore) is of coarser granularity than the notion of a transaction. However, *it is intended that there be at most one uncommitted Transaction associated with a particular Session at any time*.

As underlined above, we are discussing around something that shouldn't happen (i.e. a design problem).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an answer for your scenario because I would not implement it that way as it seems to be asking for trouble.  Instead, I'd start the transaction in C, where C invokes A and B, and have C issue the commit.  Skeletally:

```
public void c(...) {
    try {
       transaction.begin();
       a();
       b();
       transaction.commit();
    catch (Exception e) {
       transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

So here, `a()` and `b()` do not commit or rollback - how do they know the entire business task has been completed?  They could throw an exception or perhaps return a boolean to tell the caller that something is amiss and a rollback is needed.

Comment: Thanks Tony, I like the way you have mentioned it.

Comment: @Tony Ennis: plus one, and really well streamlined.